# Transition Rejection Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a HTTPInterceptor that should go to signin state whenever a 401 is caught. My problem is that I have 3 asynchronous call to API that almost starts the same time. When all of them returns 401, i got an error with the following message:

> Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: "undefined")

This is my code for my interceptor:

```
switch (response.status) {
  case 401:
    let url = $location.absUrl();
    // This condition supposed to prevent
    // going to signin state again after a response of 401.
    // Not really sure if ui-router will navigate still on the same
    // state. So maybe this condition is not needed?
    if (url.indexOf('sign-in') !== -1) {
      deferred.reject(response.data.error);
    } else {
      if ($transitions._transitionCount === 1) {
        $state.go('signin');
      }
    }
    break;
```

What ive tried so far is to check the transitionCount but still the error persist.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps check `$state.current` and if it's already `signin` then don't do `$state.go('signin')` again? It should work

Comment: Ok ill check, Thanks!

Comment: Still dont work.

Comment: $state.name returns ""

Comment: Multiple transitions to the same state  (signin) are ignored in recent versions of ui-router. See https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitions#atomicity

Comment: Yeah, I think it should not cause a problem. I'm just bothered with the error message.

Answer (score 6):

> In UI-Router legacy, users often complained that resolves would
>   “swallow errors”. The errors were output as a $stateChangeError event,
>   but applications sometimes didn’t listen to the event.
>
> In UI-Router 1.0, we’ve added a default error handler. When a call to
>   $state.go() fails, we pass the error to
>   StateService.defaultErrorHandler.

You can handle this type of error with

```
$state.defaultErrorHandler(function(error) {
// This is a naive example of how to silence the default error handler.
console.log(error);
});
```

[Details](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#default-error-handler)